# Wait for a *specific* (single) XCTestExpectation with a completion handler?

Tags: swift, xctest

Has anyone managed to wait for a specific, single, `XCTestExpectation` with completion handler (`XCWaitCompletionHandler` or equivalent) similar to that of (`waitForExpectations:timeout:handler`)[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1500748-waitforexpectations].

I want to wait for just one specific expectation, but I would like to know if it timed out. The `XCWaitCompletionHandler` gives me that information. But there are no properties on the expectation itself flagging whether it timed out or not.

(yes this is a rather advanced use case...)

Comment: I tried being clever and reading out failedTestCases count from optinal `testRun`, my idea was to check if it had increased by one, if so, likey failed with timeout. But realised it is not reliable if running multiple test in parallel? Maybe using `DispatchQueue.main.sync`?

Comment: Another “being too clever”-attempt would be to set `assertForOverFulfill` to true and call `fulfill` afterwards, but nor sure how to capture the aasert? (Meaning NO fail).

Answer (score 3):

Create an `XCTWaiter` and use [wait(for:timeout:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctwaiter/2806744-wait), which returns a [XCTWaiter.Result](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctwaiter/result), which you can then assert is/is not `.timedOut` if you wish, or otherwise act on the result. By using `XCTWaiter`, you can have an expectation time out without the test automatically failing.

```
let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 5)
if result == .timedOut { ... }
```